# export dataframe to csv inside a zip

Tags: python, pandas, csv, zip

I have a data frame and I want to export it, using `to_csv`. 
I need it to be a csv file inside a zip. 
I tried using `compression` but it did not work as planned:

```
metadata_table.to_csv(r'/tmp/meta.gz', compression='gzip')
```

this code will create a zipped file, but inside is not an excel file, it's a regular text editor file.
 if I change the file name to `.csv` I will only get a regular csv (in excel format) with all the information messed up inside.

is it possible to do it with one command? and not export to csv first, and compress into a zip after?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try saving with filename as file.csv.gz as written below:

```
import pandas as pd
data.to_csv('file.csv.gz', compression='gzip')
```

Hope this is helpful!

Comment: Glad that it is helpful!